# Right click/secondary click not working on Mojave

Tags: mojave, mouse

I'm on Mojave and this evening my right click stopped working with my Logitech MX Ergo trackball.

When I swap around the buttons using the Logitech Control Center software, it's the left button that doesn't work! So it's not something hardware related.

I also can't right click/secondary click work on the trackpad. <kbd>Control</kbd>+click works for some of the cases, but not all.

Any clues?

Comment: This does sound strange (especially if the trackpad is also not allowing right click). Try changing a trackpad/mouse setting and then restart it, and then change the trackpad/mouse setting back to its default. Sometimes a plist file may have been corrupted but changing a setting should reconfigure and create a new plist. Other suggestions are to perform a Apple diagnostic test, reboot in Safe Mode and reset NVRAM/SMC (don't think these will fix anything though). These last few are more hardware related but if both your trackpad/external mouse are having the same issue, may be a software issue

Comment: I suspect something software related as well. Or possibly connected with external port adapter?

Comment: yeah as I said, try changing a setting in mouse/trackpad settings which should hopefully overwrite the old correupted plist for them. Alternative you may be able to delete these and let the system recompile a new plist on the next reboot. But only do remove the plist if you are comfortable with doing that. I'm not sure which directory the relevant plists are located in so I would suggest searching around on the internet

Comment: Tried safe mode and all the resets - didn't help. I haven't done much with plists before, wouldn't know which ones to delete. But at least as a temoral solution I managed to remap my middle button to a right one using Logitech Options. Ordered wired mouse to see if it helps and I might try reinstall over Christmas.

Comment: I have the same problem on M1. It happened spontaneously. I have tried two external Windows mice.

Comment: it fixed itself after some time on its own, not sure what was the issue. I try not to use inbuilt keyboard or touchpad anyway....

Comment: one less anoying isue is that if I actually want to use inbuilt keyboard/touchpad I need to disconnect bluetooth keyboard/mouse